# Is there a way to return the index of an element that returns True in the any() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, any

(This is just an example of what I'd like to be solved)

```
array = ["hello", "hi"]

statement = input()

condition = any(statement in elm for elm in array)
```

Is there a way to return the index of the element that returns True, or should I just use a for loop?

Comment: What is `elm`, a set, a list?

Comment: What is query ? statement is not used ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the element that returns true"? And what do you intend to *do with* this index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you want the `index` of the statement in `array`

```
array = ["hello", "hi"]
statement = input("Give a word: ")
condition = array.index(statement) if statement in array else -1
print(condition)
```

Demo

```
Give a word: hello
0
Give a word: hi
1
Give a word: Hi
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time search the function properties. I write the example code base on [Python documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.index)

```py
array = ["hello", "hi", "example", "to get", "index from array"]

def SearchIndex():
    statement = input()
    #// Check if input is item on list
    if statement in array: print(">>", array.index(statement))

    #// Other search if input is part of item in list
    else:
        part_of = False
        for item in array:
            if statement in item:
                print('>> {0} is part of "{2}" -> {1}'.format(statement, array.index(item), array[array.index(item)]))
                #// If founded signal
                part_of = True
        #// If nout found (signal is false)
        if part_of == False: print(f">> {statement} is not on list...")

while 1:
    SearchIndex()
```

Comment: I know how to get the index using a for loop, I asked if there was a way to get the index without using a for loop, thanks anyway!

Comment: @LittleNooblet `array.index(statement)` is not a loop. I call it after **if** statement to avoid an error. What is after **else:** was just an example of how to get the index in case just one word was defined. `array.index(statement)` will return **int()** if will be a perfect match between _statemen_ and _array item_